# PHP to AJAX, only one checkbox appears

Tags: javascript

I have this error when selecting more than one values like this: 
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-D1oucKVR7rA/W0_PM1Po-9I/AAAAAAAAAjU/pWAGZCFY8cg6nHK6ALTWwSvZ38QdmsiqQCL0BGAYYCw/h544/2018-07-18.png
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jC8w5UQTKvg/W0_PNj03yJI/AAAAAAAAAjU/JBTRKBdb0_Eha5-yhVJa5F9F8B1PfY6lACL0BGAYYCw/h314/2018-07-18.png

It shows only the first one checkbox.
A piece of code:

```
for (i in json['shipping_method']) {
                    html += '<p><strong>' + json['shipping_method'][i]['title'] + '</strong></p>';

                    if (!json['shipping_method'][i]['error']) {
                        for (j in json['shipping_method'][i]['quote']) {
                            html += '<div class="radio">';
                            html += '  <label>';

                            if (json['shipping_method'][i]['quote'][j]['code'] == '<?php echo $shipping_method; ?>') {
                                html += '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[]" value="' + json['shipping_method'][i]['quote'][j]['code'] + '" checked="checked" />';
                            } else {
                                html += '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[]" value="' + json['shipping_method'][i]['quote'][j]['code'] + '" />';
                            }

                            html += json['shipping_method'][i]['quote'][j]['title'] + ' - ' + json['shipping_method'][i]['quote'][j]['text'] + '</label></div>';
                        }
                    } else {
                        html += '<div class="alert alert-danger">' + json['shipping_method'][i]['error'] + '</div>';
                    }
                }
```

Comment: There is neither PHP nor AJAX in the code you're showing

Comment: we have no idea what the input data is, nor do we know what _"this error"_ could be, ..

Comment: In the first photo, I introduced 2 types of info but with different title and description. And then if you look at the second screenshot it shows only the first one. I want it to show the second one too.

Comment: check your input data. are there two objects in `json['shipping_method'][i]['quote']`? How do you output/return the html? The example isn't verifyable/reproduceable.

Comment: Yes, they are both in there. https://pastebin.com/9zJzsGGE Here is all the code for the function